# Finding a matrix representation of a linear transformation (polynomial basis to standard basis)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, complex-numbers, linear-transformations

I'm stuck at this problem:

Let $P_3(\mathbb{C})$ denote the complex vector space of complex polynomials of degree 2 or less. Let $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C},\alpha\neq\beta$. Consider the image $L:P_3(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$ given by $L(p)=\begin{pmatrix}p(\alpha)\\ p(\beta)\end{pmatrix}\text{for} \: p\in P_3(\mathbb{C})$. Consider again the basis $\mathcal{V}=(1,X,X^2)$ for $P_3(\mathbb{C})$ and the standard basis $\mathcal{E}=(\pmb{e_1},\pmb{e_2})$ for $\mathbb{C}^2$.

1. Find the matrix representation $_\mathcal{E}[L]_\mathcal{V}$ for $L$ with regards to $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{E}$.

What do I do? If you have any literature that can help me understand what to do, I will greatly appreciate you would give me a link :S

Comment: Any more or less decent book in linear algebra covers this very basic subject.

Comment: Too bad that I and my peers have this crappy e-book that we use at our university.

Comment: That is hardly an explanation: there are hundreds of thousands of sites in the web that deal with this subject, and there are even many online book you can check or even download about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be a $2 \times 3$ matrix, since $P_3$ is 3-dimensional, and $\Bbb{C}^2$ is 2-dimensional. The first column should be the image of the first basis vector of $P_3$, which is $p(x) = 1$. Regardless of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, you get $L(1) = \binom{1}{1}$.

Now, for the second basis vector, $p(x) = x$, the image of $L$ is $L(x) = \binom{\alpha}{\beta}$.

Finally, for the third, $p(x) = x^2$, and we get $L(x^2) = \binom{\alpha^2}{\beta^2}$.

So the matrix is given by

$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & \alpha & \alpha^2 \\ 1 & \beta & \beta^2 \end{array} \right) $$

Comment: Thank you. That was just what I needed. Do you know any literature that you could recommend for Linear Algebra?